# Temperature and Humidity does not print on LCD

Tags: gpio, python, python-3, raspberry-pi-os, lcd

I am working with a DHT 11 and LCD.  When executing the code, the temperature prints one time on the pc and freezes.  It does not print on the LCD though neither.  Can I have someone assist me with this problem, please?

[image]

Comment: Not a Pi, but a Python problem... Pls post the code as text, but first make sure you initialise the LCD just once. You're doing that every time you try to write new values and that will not work..

Comment: import os
from time import sleep
import RPLCD import CharLCD
import RPi.GPIO as GPIOimport gpiozero

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

humidity, temperatureC = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 4)
termperature = temperatureC * (9/5) + 32;

def configure_lcd():
    lcd = CharLCD(numbering_mode = GPIO.BCM, cols=16, rows=2, pin_rs=37, pin_e=35, pins_data=[33, 31, 29, 23]))
    lcd.write_string('Temp = {0:4.1}F'.format(termperature))
    lcd.cursor_pos = (0, 0)
    lcd.cursor_pos = (0, 1)
    lcd.write_string('Hum = {0:4.1f} ^'.format(humidity))

Comment: while temperature
    if humidity and temperature is not None:
        print('Temp = {0:4.2} Farenhet Humidty = {0:4.2f}%'.format(temperature, humidity))

        configure_lcd()

    sleep(2)

Comment: IDK why it came out that way. I could post it all at once. you're only give a certain amount of character

Comment: You have to add any updates to the question itself, not the comments.